# Invariant factors and elementary divisors of quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I need help solving the following problem:

> Let $G = \Bbb{Z}_9 \times \Bbb{Z}_9 \times \Bbb{Z}_9$ be the product of three cyclic groups of order 9. Give invariant factors and elementary divisors of the quotient group $G/H$ when
>
> a) $H= \langle (6, 6, 6)\rangle \subset G$
>
> b) $H = \langle (1, 3, 0), (1, 0, 3) \rangle \subset G$

I only got so far as to determine the order of the quotient group in each case: for part a), I know $H=|\langle (6,6,6)\rangle| =3$, so $G/H$ has order $729/3=243$ and at least intuitively, this seems to point in the direction of $G/H \cong \Bbb{Z}_9 \times \Bbb{Z}_9 \times \Bbb{Z}_3$, but I am not sure about this.

For part b), $|H|=|\langle (1, 3, 0), (1, 0, 3) \rangle|=9$, but I don't know how to proceed from here, as $|G/H| = 81$ in this case, but I don't know what to do next to determine the correct decomposition.

Is there any consistent method of solving problems like this one? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your notation is strikingly different. Do you mean, for example, $(6,6,6)$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Your tally in part b) is off. The element $(1,3,0)$ has order nine, thanks to the first component. And $(1,0,3)$ is not one of the multiples, so there will be more.

Comment: Your intuition about part a) is correct, though. One way to make it more precise would be to use the generating set $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(1,1,1)$ for $G$. That choice leads to a stacked bases kind of a situation between $G$ and $H$.